# making sublists from a list and adding all sublists in one list in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, sublist

Can anybody help me with list concepts?
I have a List of names and I want to make sublists of words with the same letter  then add all those sublists in a list.
this is my code:

```
  List<String> items = [
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    'five',
    'six',
    'seven',
    'eight',
    'nine',
    'ten'
  ];
  List<String> sublist;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //----- sort alphabetically
    items.sort((a, b) =>
        a.toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.toString().toLowerCase()));
    //----- get the initials
    sublist = items.map((element) => element[0]).toList();
    //----- remove duplicates
    sublist = sublist.toSet().toList();
    // ---------------- generate lists
    List s = [];
    List<List> listOfLists = [];
    sublist.forEach((letter) async {
      items.forEach((item) =>
          item.startsWith(letter) ? s.add(item) : {items.iterator.moveNext()});
      listOfLists.add(s);
      print(letter);
      print(s);
      s.clear();
    });
    print(listOfLists);
```

this is what I want to get from listOfList : [ [eight], [five, four], [nine], [one], [seven, six], [ten, three, two] ]
but I just get empty sublists:
Here is my result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQmGc.png)

Comment: What should the final result look like?

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the lists in each iteration.

Remove s.clear() and move List s = [] inside the for each function

```
// ---------------- generate lists
    List<List> listOfLists = [];
    sublist.forEach((letter) async {
      List s = [];

      items.forEach((item) => item.startsWith(letter) ? s.add(item) : {items.iterator.moveNext()});
      listOfLists.add(s);
      print(letter);
      print(s);
    });
```

Anyway, I would recommend you not to use forEach inside another forEach

You can then use:

```
    List<List> listOfLists = [];
    sublist.forEach((letter) async {
      List s = items.where((item) => item.startsWith(letter)).toList();
      listOfLists.add(s);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used  `where` and it works fine.  You are not recommending to use forEach inside another forEach, why is that?

Comment: I have different reasons. In this case, the main reason is that the code remains cleaner. Everything is easier when you see what the code does at a glance. This is very important when you are working as part of a team. However, another reason is the force of habit. It is said that nested loops can cause performance issues. They may not have a big impact if you are working with a simple client application but I would say it is better to acquire the habit to avoid them if possible. Nevertheless, I think where function may have loops inside as well, but I expect it to work faster than my own loop

Comment: Thanks for you answer.